# How to use Msgpack between a C# program and a Node.js program?

Tags: c#, node.js, serialization, zeromq, msgpack

I've successfully transfered data from a C# and a C++ program using the same class via ZMQ, where the C++ class is the data definition and the compiler luckily masks the byte-array to the class.

How would I do the same thing between say a C# and a Node.js program? I would think they would need some type of Intermediate Data Definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you need an [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) that is then compiled to your given languages, unless your languages pack similarly by default, like in C to C++.

If you need a msgpack IDL, see if one is available [here](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-idl) or [here](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-haskell/tree/master/msgpack-idl)

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at the [node-msgpack repository on github](https://github.com/pgriess/node-msgpack)...  Then install it... `npm install msgpack`

There's also [msgpack-js](https://github.com/creationix/msgpack-js) an all-js implementation that may work better, especially if you're running on windows. `npm install msgpack-js`

I would suggest being careful of the types used as JS doesn't have a 1:1 relationship to msgpack or the CLI.  It *should* map pretty nicely, though the C# MsgPack API isn't as flexible as say JSON.Net  As for transport, you can use pipes/sockets or an MQ system, as you've mentioned ZeroMQ.

Comment: I would think there would need to be an IDL so each given language understands the data type. Is this not true?